# Xamarin Android: how to share a string via text/email/Whatsapp/Facebook/WeChat

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, social-networking

My Xamarin app for Android reads some local data, process them and returns the results as a string like: 
"Current target is X, please increase power to Y". 
I want to have a button in my app that will open the usual sshare command that we see in many applications and where it is possible to say that the content will be shared with the apps that you have on your phone. 
For example if I use WeChat or even WhatsApp I can click on that icon and select the contact to share my string. 
How can I achieve this in Xamarin. In particular, I would need to interact with WeChat, WhatsApp and Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to have a button in my app that will open the usual sshare command that we see in many applications and where it is possible to say that the content will be shared with the apps that you have on your phone.

You can refer to the official doc: [Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) for Android, in Xamarin.Android, it's similar, for example:

```
Intent intentsend = new Intent();
intentsend.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
intentsend.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "Current target is X, please increase power to Y");
intentsend.SetType("text/plain");
StartActivity(intentsend);
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work as expected. Only thing is that once you share the first time, for example choosing WhatsApp, that app will be the default for any further button click in future. Is there an easy way to get a dialog that each time asks me what app to use for sharing?

Comment: @opt, very sorry for the late responding. I think you can use [clearPackagePreferredActivities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#clearPackagePreferredActivities%28java.lang.String%29) in `PackageManager` for this issue.

Comment: @opt
This is what I did to make sure that the dialog to choose an app shows up every time.

`StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intentsend, "Share Via"));`

Answer (score 1):

I personally have not tried that as I do not need it this far. However, I found this [`Xamarin.Social`](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.social) package and probably sharing to you is helpful. Here is [the example](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Social/blob/master/samples/Xamarin.Social.Sample.Android/MainActivity.cs) at their GitHub repo. I will attach the code snippet from their example so it is easier to you to read here.

```
//taken from https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Social/blob/master/samples/Xamarin.Social.Sample.Android/MainActivity.cs 
void Share (Service service, Button shareButton)
{
    Item item = new Item {
        Text = "I'm sharing great things using Xamarin!",
        Links = new List<Uri> {
        new Uri ("http://xamarin.com"),
        },
    };

    Intent intent = service.GetShareUI (this, item, shareResult => {
        shareButton.Text = service.Title + " shared: " + shareResult;
    });

    StartActivity (intent);
}

public override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    ...
    facebookButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
        try
        {
            Share (Facebook, facebookButton); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowMessage("Facebook: " + ex.Message);
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I saw Xamarin.Social but it doesn't support all the app I need now, while the solution proposed by Grace Feng seems to work with any app on my phone. But even for Facebook, do you see any additional value in using Xamarin.Social over the other proposed solution? Thanks again.